# I'm trying to make my PyQt GUI code in OOP way

Tags: python, oop, pyqt5

I'm trying to make my PyQt5 GUI in OOP way for example class for window and another for Pushbutton I'm really confiuse how to make it.Here is my code and my try to make pushbutton class.also my goal is to make classes for each of the items in the window

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
     def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        #making Pushbutton
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 210, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton::setCheckable(bool)")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
       self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
# here I'm trying to make Buttom class
class Button(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Button, self).__init__(parent)


# Main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Sorry but your question is really unclear (and it also seems incomplete). Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to write all iteams in my window as classes

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Do you want to create subclasses for *each* widget you're using? What's the reason of that?

Comment: yes subclasses I think It would be better and more elegant

Comment: @Izzo Better and more elegant? I don't see that that is true. If you want to create a custom QPushButton then inherit from QPushButton, and then change `self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)` with `self.pushButton = Button(self.centralwidget)`

Comment: maybe I'm wrong but anyway I want to learn

Comment: There's nothing wrong in being eager to learn. But the purpose should not be confused with the method. By looking at your code you seem to be still learning how PyQt works, and I strongly suggest you to begin with understanding how Qt, its classes and subclasses behave, and by studying the documentation. As a side note, consider that you should *never* edit the output of `pyuic` (nor try to mimic its code). Read more about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to understand how to use ui files.

Comment: thanks for the advice

Comment: [Differences between Procedural and Object Oriented Programming](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/differences-between-procedural-and-object-oriented-programming/) [Functional vs Object-Oriented vs Procedural Programming](https://medium.com/@LiliOuakninFelsen/functional-vs-object-oriented-vs-procedural-programming-a3d4585557f3)

Comment: musicamante and eyllanesc are very good experts and resourcefull but as a beginner myself I found not easy to start with Qt documentation, I mean I dont understand C and I am missing very basic concepts about programming. Its easy to find tutorial on PyQt5 , its more difficult to find out a tutorial that starts with basic programming concepts.

Comment: I think my problem is understanding the pyqt classes therefore I just need the very basic example to how converting it to oop to make me understand the whole idea

Comment: Object oriented programming can be defined as a programming model which is based upon the concept of objects. Objects contain data in the form of attributes and code in the form of methods. In object oriented programming, computer programs are designed using the concept of objects that interact with real world. Object oriented programming languages are various but the most popular ones are class-based, meaning that objects are instances of classes, which also determine their types.

Comment: [The QObject class is the base class of all Qt objects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html) click on more to have better description

Comment: [MIT6001](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-0001-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-in-python-fall-2016/readings/) I started from here but got stuck at lesson 4, OOP is at 8. Slides are nice [slides lesson 8](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-0001-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-in-python-fall-2016/lecture-slides-code/MIT6_0001F16_Lec8.pdf)

Comment: thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 0):

from [Subclassing of QPushButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250888/subclassing-of-qpushbutton) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Jun  6 16:21:24 2020

@author: Pietro
"""

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        #making Pushbutton
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 210, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton::setCheckable(bool)")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.pippo=CustomButtonClass(self.centralwidget)
        self.pippo.show()


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

# here I'm trying to make Buttom class
class CustomButtonClass(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QPushButton.__init__(self,*args, **kwargs)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 310, 93, 28))
        self.setText('customized')
        self.hide()
        self.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
            "    background-color: #9de650;\n"
            "}\n"
            "\n"
            "\n"
            "QPushButton:hover{\n"
            "    background-color: green;\n"
            "}\n"
            "\n"
            "")

# Main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```